# Untracking C drive in git

Tags: git, github

I mistakenly dìd git init in my C drive and git start tracking the whole of my  C drive.
Would anyone know how do I stop or untrack this feature, please?
I have tried to delete the repository on gitHub but every time I try to create a repository in any folder on my C drive I end up getting the same error returned while pushing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A git repository can be removed by removing the `.git` folder. You can enable showing hidden folders by using the following steps:

1. In the search box on the taskbar, type folder, and then select Show hidden files and folders from the search results.
2. Under Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then select OK.

Then finding and deleting the `.git` folder.

More info about showing hidden files: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful have been able to untrack the C drive